# trouble iterating through dictionary keys and values in django template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to iterate through a context dictionary in a template in django. So far I've been unsuccessful and I'm not understanding what it is wrong.

This is my view:

```
def main_view(request):
    cat_dict = {'Other': 0,
                  'Meeting': 0,
                  'Project 1': 0,
                  'Project 2': 0,
                  'Project 3': 0,
                  'Project 4': 0,
                  'Collaboration 1': 0,
                  'Collaboration 2': 0,
                  'Collaboration 3': 0,
                  'Process 1': 0
                  }
    my_dict = gCalScriptMain.gCalScript(cat_dict)
    return render(request, 'gCalData/gCalData_main.html', context=my_dict)
```

Instead, this is my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron index-jumbotron">
    <h1 id="main-title">gCalData</h1>
    <ul style="color:white">

      {% for k,v in my_dict.items %}
          <li>{{ k }}: {{ v }}</li>

      {% endfor %}

    </ul>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

But I get nothing (not even an error).
The only thing I can do is retrieve a single value if I put this in the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron index-jumbotron">
    <h1 id="main-title">gCalData</h1>
    <p style="color:white">{{ Other }}</p>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Uh are you sure that's how dicts work in django?

Comment: Do you mean the iteration in the template? It's based other questions I saw on stack overflow. Unless I'm making a mistake that I'm not being able to see for myself (not unlikely since I'm still learning)

Comment: The iteration is probably ok, but normally you have to use something like my_dict[k] to get the values.

Comment: I've just tried but with my_dict[k] I get a parsing error

Comment: Damn, try my_dict.k? That's where i could focus my efforts anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` that you give to `render` function is dictionary of variables you can use in template. This means that you can use `Other`, `Meeting`, etc.

If you want to use your dictionary, then you need to do

```
...
return render(request, 'gCalData/gCalData_main.html', context={"my_dict": my_dict})
```

and then you can iterate over `my_dict` in template.